# Unable to update head_title string in template_preprocess_html

Tags: theming, 7

I wanted to add some data to the page head title and created a template_preprocess_html function in my module.

I added a couple entries to the head_title_array and imploded the array back into head_title.

At first it looked like it wasnt working at all, but then I checked and in html.tpl.php the $head_title_array was updated.

My temp solution is to implode the array there before printing it but that's a little hackish for me.

Thoughts on where the title is being set or re-set to prevent it from being changed in template_preprocess_html?

Module code is aproximately:

```
function MODULE_preprocess_html(&$variables) {
  $head_title = $variables['head_title_array'];
  array_unshift($head_title, 'TEST');

  $variables['head_title_array'] = $head_title;
  $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', $head_title);
}
```

and in html.tpl.php:

```
<title><?php print implode(' | ', $head_title_array); ?></title>
```

I just noticed that the metadata module is storing variables in an array called metatag_set_preprocess_variable.  That might be the cause, I'll investigate further.

Comment: How were you setting the page head title? Seems like you should be calling drupal_add_html_head() in your hook_preprocess_html() and setting the title tag in there.

Comment: Not sure about in general, but in the Zen template the head tag is printed in html.tpl.php so I probably shouldn't set it directly. That's a new function for me though that will be useful for some other metadata.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you find that `$head_title` is different from `implode(' | ', $head_title_array)`, it means there is a module running after yours that implements `hook_preprocess_html()` which runs after your implementation, or `hook_process_html()`.

The code executed from Drupal is the following:

- [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) (It runs before `hook_preprocess_html()`.)

  ```
  // Construct page title.
  if (drupal_get_title()) {
    $head_title = array(
      'title' => strip_tags(drupal_get_title()), 
      'name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')),
    );
  }
  else {
    $head_title = array('name' => check_plain(variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')));
    if (variable_get('site_slogan', '')) {
      $head_title['slogan'] = filter_xss_admin(variable_get('site_slogan', ''));
    }
  }
  $variables['head_title_array'] = $head_title;
  $variables['head_title'] = implode(' | ', $head_title);

  // Populate the page template suggestions.
  if ($suggestions = theme_get_suggestions(arg(), 'html')) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'] = $suggestions;
  }
  ```
- [template_process_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_process_html/7) (It runs after `hook_preprocess_html()`, but before `hook_process_html()`.)

  There is no code that alters `$variables['head_title_array']`, or `$variables['head_title']`.

The fact `$head_title_array` contains the value you expect makes me think there is really a module that implements `hook_preprocess_html` to alter `$variables['head_title']`.

To be sure your module is the last one running `hook_preprocess_html()`, you need to make your module weight higher.

Answer (score 2):

try to paste this into devel/php :

```
dpm(module_implements('preprocess_html'));
dpm(module_implements('process_html'));
```